# How to adjust Magento 2 Thumbnail slider Width so the arrows are not "over the slider"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Magento 2 the arrows of the thumbnail slider are "over the thumbs".

What I want is this : < image 1 image 2 >

An example can be seen in the magento marketplace itself.

https://marketplace.magento.com/aheadworks-module-rma.html

Here is a random product I took from the homepage, as u can see the arrows are nicely visible than in middle you have the thumbs.

On my site, the arrows are over the thumbnails as the shaft is equal width of the gallery.

I think this is done in fotorama.js but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance!